# how to parse string and convert to array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

I have a string like this:

```
$str = '{{id}{378}}{{details}{{useranme}{mohamad13}}{{phone}{0712345678}}{{name}{Mohammad}}{{language}{persian}}{{city}{kabul}}}{{email}{name@email.com}}{{time}{{reg_time}{1520452574}}{{last_visit}{1520452574}}{{birth_day}{1520452574}}}';



// This is prety vertion of $str variable:

$str = '
    {{id}{378}}

    {{details}
        {{useranme}{mohamad13}}
        {{phone}{0712345678}}
        {{name}{Mohammad}}
        {{language}{persian}}
        {{city}{kabul}}
    }

    {{email}{name@email.com}}

    {{time}
        {{reg_time}{1520452574}}
        {{last_visit}{1520452574}}
        {{birth_day}{1520452574}}
    }';
```

I need to a function that get string parameter like `$str` and return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 378
    [email] => name@email.com
    [details] => Array
        (
            [useranme] => mohamad13
            [phone] => 0712345678
            [name] => Mohammad
            [language] => persian
            [city] => kabul
        )

    [time] => Array
        (
            [reg_time] => 1520452574
            [last_visit] => 1520452574
            [birth_day] => 1520452574
        )

)
```

It is important that first set the uncategoried values like 'id' and 'email' then categoried values;

thanks. sorry my language is not english. I am persian.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Whatever created that should be able to parse it.  If you created it, then consider JSON instead.

Comment: Note that your example array is technically incorrect, all those unquoted array keys are going to be tossing undefined constant errors into the error log.

Comment: @Mark that is exactly how most people display an array here. It's an exact copy of a var_dump if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Andreas Sure but it doesn't make it correct code, and if you want to use the array and write a function that outputs that (exactly) to a PHP variable it's also not correct. Since the user specified 'return array' it seems worth pointing out that a return array exactly like they specified is improper PHP syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be some defined format I'm not familiar with, but if not then you could convert it to JSON and decode that. It's easy enough with the example input you've shown:

```
$quotes = preg_replace('/{([^{}]+)}/', '"$1"' , $str);
$json = str_replace(['""', '}{', '"{'], ['":"', ',', '":{'], $quotes);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

This is just based on your example, though. It certainly isn't guaranteed to work if the input string is more complex. You'd have to do more testing with different inputs and probably make some adjustments.

Once you have an array, you can just `asort($data)` to get the single value keys first.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Your provide code is that I have need.